# Open console source mapped file in external editor

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When you use source maps on errors, the Chrome Developer Tools console shows links to the source file.

Is there a way to open these links in an external application (editor)?

For instance, on click or CTRL+click or...

Comment: Nope, not yet. But this comes close by changing your source code fast ;) http://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/

Comment: [Same question for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094789/use-external-editor-in-firefox-devtools), for anyone interested (and same status for now.)

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, this isn’t possible yet.**

Here are some links that may help:

- http://sokolovstas.github.io/SublimeWebInspector/
- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en
- https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/
- https://gregrickaby.com/2013/07/turn-chrome-developer-tools-into-an-ide/
- [Sublime text 3 and Web Inspector plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370473/sublime-text-3-and-web-inspector-plugin)
- https://medium.com/google-developers/devtools-tips-for-sublime-text-users-cdd559ee80f8#.wck48zrkz

Answer (score 1):

Possible in 2020 using Intellij (IDE in my case).

1. Install "Open in Intellij" extension (Chrome)
2. Configure as here in docs https://github.com/bernhardc/open-in-intellij

Worked like a charm.

Comment: This is a great solution, but you need to install https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19991-ide-remote-control plugin in recent versions of IntelliJ to make it work. I also had to add a mapping for my development address in the browser plugin as: http://mylocalserver.local:3000/ -> `/`. Also note to type a `/` in the right hand side of the mapper, you need to actually type `//` which will become `/` on save.