# Sublime text 3 and Web Inspector plugin

Tags: debugging, plugins, web, sublimetext, inspector

Am I the only person having problems with this [plugin](http://sokolovstas.github.io/SublimeWebInspector/) in Sublime Text 3? I cloned it from github repo, and when I try to start chrome's remote debugging via Sublime's command pallete, the new instance of chrome is being opened but the file is not being opened. Did anybody made this plugin to work is ST3? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Before working with Web Inspector plugin, properly exit chrome.

In chrome use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are using the [`ST3`](https://github.com/sokolovstas/SublimeWebInspector/tree/ST3) branch of the github repo, and have run `git pull` as there have been some changes in the last few hours and days. Also, make sure you read completely through the [Getting Started](https://github.com/sokolovstas/SublimeWebInspector/blob/master/README.markdown#getting-started) section of the README. It looks like you need to manually open your application's URL in Chrome after you've started it via Sublime using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - you can't use an already-running Chrome session. You can then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> again and choose "Start debugging", then choose the correct tab from the list.

If you're still having issues, I'd fill out a detailed [issue](https://github.com/sokolovstas/SublimeWebInspector/issues/new) on Github and let the developer know what's going on. Make sure you include all the steps you've followed, and the complete text of any error messages that may appear in the Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>).