# Use external editor in Firefox devtools?

Tags: javascript, firefox-developer-tools

If I click on a filename with line number (`script.js:100:4`) in the Firefox developer tools, it takes me to an integrated editor. Is there a way to open an external editor (at the correct line) instead (for example, VS Code)?

There is a [similar question for *Chrome*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260194/open-console-source-mapped-file-in-external-editor) from 2013, where it was not (yet?) possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no option yet to open the sources in an external editor. I've [filed an enhancement request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1270733) for that a long time ago.