# Make source map point to actual file on disk (and not copy in map)

Tags: javascript, webpack, firefox-developer-tools

When using Firefox devtools with source maps, the devtools editor shows the source as saved in the bundle or source map. I would like to get it to show the actual file on disk.

I tried adding the following in my webpack.config.js:

```
output: {
    filename: "./source/js/bundle.js",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: 'file://[absolute-resource-path]',
    devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: "file://[absolute-resource-path]?[hash]",
},
devtool: 'source-map',
// ...
```

but apparently, this only changes how the filenames are *displayed* inside devtools (the key names should give a hint to that). I would rather have it save the actual `file://`path, and have the devtools open the actual file from disk. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: When you do the above, what ends up in the generated source map?  If it is `file:` URLs, then I would expect it to work ok.  If it is not `file:` URLs, then maybe webpack needs some additional tweaking somehow.

Comment: It does have the file: URLs, but when I view source in the devtools debugger, the files have "WEBPACK FOOTER" comments in them, and they don't reflect changes I've made on disk. The paths given there are just for display in the devtools. I could replace `file://` with `webpack://` or `foo://bar`.(Granted, using sourcemaps with modified files is not very useful. I'm ultimately trying to teach firefox the correct paths so I can click on a link in devtools and [open the corresponding source in my editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094789) - which might need a custom extension.)

Comment: I think at this point you should file a bug report in bugzilla and attach details there.